# command line arguments not being recognised

Tags: python, command-line

Im trying to send some command line arguments to a program I've written. I adapted some code I found in a tutorial. However, only the last of the arguments I am sending seam to be getting through. For example, if I type the following in:

```
python test.py -m A
```

Nothing happens, however, if I type in:

```
python test.py -s A
```

the final argument in the list it seams to work... (code attached below)

```
import sys, getopt

def main(argv):
    mina = ""
    capsize= ""
    matchcharge= ""
    steps= ""

try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"m:cs:mc:s:",["min=","capsize=","matchcharge=","steps="])
except getopt.GetoptError:
    print("argument not recognised")
    sys.exit(2)
for opt, arg in opts:
    if opt == ("-m", "--min"):
        mina = arg
        print("1")
    elif opt in ("-cs", "--capsize"):
        capsize = arg
        print("2")
    elif opt in ("-mc", "--matchcharge"):
        matchcharge = arg
        print("3")
    elif opt in ("-s", "--steps"):
        steps = arg
        print("4")

print("mina " + str(min))
print("capsize" + str(capsize))
print("matchcharge" + str(matchcharge))
print("steps " + str(steps))


if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you have

```
if opt == ("-m", "--min"):
```

which should be

```
if opt in ("-m", "--min"):
```

Since you had that right on all the other places, I guess this was just forgotten there.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I made that change, however, the code still dosen't work. if I put in the following argument (for example) "test.py -m min -cs cs -mc mc -s s". min gets set to "c" and steps get set to "cs". Is there anything else I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to make `cs` and `mc` also long flags. Currently `"m:cs:mc:s:"` means that for arguments `m, s, c and s` there should be attributes but `c` and `m` can be used such as.

Comment: Take a look at the docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html

I would also recommend using `argparse` https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse for easier command-line arguments processing